# Account to shard correspondence

Tags: nearprotocol

User issued a transaction with a `Transfer` action to some `receiver_id`. How node determines to which shard this transaction must be routed?

Answer (score 3):

It is determined by `RuntimeAdapter`, which has a method `account_id_to_shard_id` that maps account id to shard id.